# Building a Debian package with two buildsystem

Tags: packaging

I have a package that needs to be build with both a regular `makefile` and a `setup.py`. The thing is that the Debian packaging magic that is invoked via `debuild` would recognize a `makefile` and do the right

```
make
make install DESTDIR=???
```

thing and get it working right. When I only have a `setup.py` sitting there and have `dh $@ --with python3 --buildsystem pybuild` in `debian/rules`, it will correctly install the Python module with

```
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install --install-layout deb --root=??? ???
```

I do not know all those flags. And I think that I do not need to. I just want the `makefile` magic to happen, and then the `setup.py` magic.

**How can I tell `debuild` to do both?**

When I do the following in `debian/rules`

```
%:
        dh $@
        dh $@ --with python3 --buildsystem pybuild
```

it will only put the first one into the resulting package. I tried to delete the `debhelper.log` between those, but that did not change much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both but in that case your `debian/rules` will exclusively use overrides:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@ --with=python3

override_dh_auto_build:
    make universe-explode-in-delight
    cd python_src && python3 setup.py build

override_dh_auto_test:
    cd python_src && python3 setup.py test

override_dh_auto_install:
    cd python_src && python3 setup.py install \
        --force --root=$(CURDIR)/debian/tmp \
        --no-compile -O0 --install-layout=deb
    make install_non_python_stuff

override_dh_auto_clean:
    cd python_src && python3 setup.py clean
```

See: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dh.1.html

Comment: I changed the destination directory to `$(CURDIR)/debian/PACKAGENAME`, but it works otherwise.